# Как ограничить ip адресу вход на свой сайт?

Tags: apache, tcp-ip, windows-server

Как ограничить ip адресу вход на свой сайт?

Comment: Уточните, какими средствами, под какой OS. Можно и системными ip tables, и настройкой веб сервера Apache или nginx - что у вас?

Comment: apache, win server. просто один спамщик спамит и я хочу ему заблокировать доступ к сайту

Comment: Для Apache в .htaccess в корне сайта прописать:

    order allow,deny
    deny from 1.2.3.4
    allow from all

где 1.2.3.4 — IP спамера. Но он тут же переключиться на новый, скорее всего.

Comment: спасибо)), то что надо. там точнее ip украинского вшивого провайдера; не станет же спамщик менять провайдер из-за блокировки)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$ip = (string) "ip banned";
if($ip == (string)$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
    die ("text");
}
?>
```

вариантов много, можно и в `htaccess` сделать, так же если хочешь ограничить доступ к сайту ещё с многими ип то можно занести все ип в массив, так же с текстовым файлом или бд.

Comment: "ip banned" - это тот ip адрес который надо заблокировать?

Comment: @Kapone да, именно он